# How to use the Ruby map method to limit the parameters sent via an API

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Consider the follow:

```
@posts = Post.all
render json: { success: true, data: @posts }
```

Now, each `post` will have parameters that are not required to be sent in this particular scenario (although it'll be in others), so I'd like to restrict the parameters sent and I thought maybe I could use `map` like so:

```
@posts = Post.all.map { |user| [user.email, user.first_name, user.last_name] }
render json: { success: true, data: @posts }
```

As you can imagine that doesn't work. Its very likely I'm using - or intending to use - map in a completely incorrect way and I'd appreciate your comments on how to achieve the above.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of [`Hash#slice`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#slicing) method to do something like:

```
@posts = Post.all.map { |user| user.as_json.slice("email", "first_name", "last_name") }
```

The `@posts` will be an array of Hash in this case, with each hash containing three key-value pairs.

Comment: This is a nice answer and better than the one I posted and deleted. I still suspect that `user` is an association of `post` and that the OP really needs ... `{ |post| post.user.as_json.slice("email", "first_name", "last_name") }`

Comment: @SteveTurczyn Thanks for the compliments., and yes, that is a possibility and your answer made me thinking for a bit.

Answer (score 1):

It may be more appropriate to use a serializer.

You'll have to install the `active_model_serializers` gem first.

An example serializer for your `Post` controller would be:

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :email,
             :first_name,
             :last_name,

end
```

You'll use the serializer in this manner (I'm assuming you'd call it in the `index` method):

```
def index
    posts = Mentor.all

    render(
      json: ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(
        posts,
        each_serializer: PostSerializer,
        root: 'posts'
      )
    )
  end
```